# A word for a parody that is also a good example of the thing parodied

Tags: single-word-requests

A friend is struggling to remember a word.  It was for a parody of X which is also a good example of X. For example a parody of westerns which is also a good western in its own right.  There are some comedy bands who do parodies of various genres of music that are also good examples of their genres. He came across this word in a review he read some time, has a decent vocabulary and we've been through the obvious : burlesque etc.  He thinks the exact meaning was something that was both a parody and a sincere example of the thing that it's parodying.

eta: I obviously haven't phrased myself well. An example he gave was the film "Isn't It Romantic" which parodies romantic comedies while still being a good romantic comedy. (tips hat to Mari-Lou)
 Another example might be Alberto y Lost Trios Paranoias whose song "Heads down no nonsense mindless boogie" - a parody of bands like Status Quo was really popular with Quo fans.

Comment: Sorry, but this question sticks in my craw. A parody cannot be a parody and also be an example of what is not being parodied. If you remove the parody elements, it ain't a parody anymore. It's just the thing itself.

Comment: @Lambie If you consider a parody of a comedy film, it could well be classed as a comedy film. OP is getting into tricky waters when they consider whole classes (parodying Westerns as a whole).

Comment: What @Lambie said. But you might just be thinking of something like ***homage*** or ***tribute*** - *something that shows respect or attests to the worth or influence of another [artistic work].*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/homage)

Comment: 'Galaxy Quest for example if you remove all the homour you would still have a decent SF film.' But then you're addressing the question [What is] 'a word for a parody that would also be a good example of the thing parodied if all the humour was removed'. If the film is a good example of the genre as it stands, I think you're confined to comedy. // The occasional allusion to a previous daft film doesn't stop a newer film being a good example of a genre. But it would hardly be a parody.

Comment: Maybe the movie "Blazing Saddles" is a a western and a *caricature*? Satirical?

Comment: *Blazing Saddles* was an excellent "comedy". And *Family Guy* Season 4 Episode 7 *(Brian the Bachelor)* was both an excellent parody of *Blazing Saddles* ***and*** an excellent comedy in its own right, imho. But the difference is one's a *western*, and the other's a *cartoon*.

Comment: I don't see how any "parody" can also be a true "high quality representative example" of the very thing it parodies (obviously *Blazing Saddles* itself is a parody of both "classic" and "spaghetti" westerns, but it's hardly "representative" of those earlier genres).

Comment: For me, the question is an aporia. Fumble Fingers, you seem to be agreeing with my first comment.

Comment: Self-parody : an artistic work in earnest that is so derivative or cliched as to be considered a parody of those works it is like.

Comment: @Mitch: 'an artistic work in earnest that is so derivative it 'as to be considered a plagiarism of those works it is like'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth a minimal google search gives many dictionaries' worth of definitions that seem to be different from ours. For example, "Self-parody definition is - representation of oneself or itself that has the character or appearance of a parody"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-parody). I suppose this is literally the case, but I also suppose the usages I am thinking of are one-offs that show such a very particular characteristic extreme style that an unknown viewer/reader would think the work a true parody of works that came before.

Comment: 'One man's parody / emulation is another's court-case'.